# Tomcat [9.0.26] - SSLHandshake Exception

Tags: spring-mvc, ssl, tomcat, tomcat9, sslhandshakeexception

My application in tomcat (version 9.0.26) is interacting with a third party HTTPS webservice. In the proces of SSL negotiation, the handshake fails and I am looking for help with the debug.

Tomcat startup parameters are:

> INFO: Command line argument:
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\tomcat32\9.0.26\conf\MyTrustStore.p12 Dec 08, 2019 8:56:08 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=MyPass Dec 08, 2019
>   8:56:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Command line argument: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS12 Dec 08,
>   2019 8:56:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Command line argument:
>   -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager Dec 08, 2019 8:56:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   lifecycleEvent INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library
>   [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0]. Dec 08, 2019 8:56:08 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. Dec 08, 2019 8:56:08 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO:
>   APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
>   Dec 08, 2019 8:56:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   initializeSSL INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c 
>   28 May 2019] Dec 08, 2019 8:56:09 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Dec 08, 2019 8:56:10 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Dec 08, 2019 8:56:10 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Server initialization
>   in [2,592] milliseconds Dec 08, 2019 8:56:10 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service [Catalina]

On enabling SSL debug logs, I captured below on the logs

> Allow unsafe renegotiation: false Allow legacy hello messages: true Is
>   initial handshake: true Is secure renegotiation: false Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for
>   TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for
>   TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for
>   TLSv1.1 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1.1 %% No cached client session update handshake state:
>   client_hello[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake) upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
>   *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1558998647 bytes = { 181, 223, 221, 91, 197, 4, 57, 190, 202, 50, 65, 37, 54, 151, 211, 23, 88,
>   35, 181, 111, 187, 68, 160, 166, 229, 25, 76, 123 } Session ID:  {}
>   Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] Compression Methods:  { 0 }
>   Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1,
>   secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1,
>   sect571r1, secp256k1} Extension ec_point_formats, formats:
>   [uncompressed] Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms:
>   SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA,
>   SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA,
>   SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA Extension extended_master_secret Extension
>   server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0),
>   value=certservicesgateway.Bingonline.com]**
>    http-nio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 236 http-nio-8080-exec-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 89 check
>   handshake state: server_hello[2]
>    **ServerHello, TLSv1.2 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1119462208 bytes = { 96, 236, 134, 31, 185, 89, 247, 95, 189, 217, 105, 127, 42, 183, 115, 120,
>   142, 31, 103, 111, 54, 50, 166, 58, 130, 107, 63, 128 } Session ID: 
>   {15, 155, 163, 64, 244, 187, 119, 250, 40, 154, 103, 47, 201, 208,
>   211, 136, 114, 116, 248, 159, 173, 34, 212, 74, 194, 65, 71, 17, 39,
>   181, 196, 228} Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   Compression Method: 0 Extension renegotiation_info,
>   renegotiated_connection:  Extension ec_point_formats, formats:
>   [uncompressed, ansiX962_compressed_prime, ansiX962_compressed_char2]
>   *** %% Initialized:  [Session-6, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
>   ** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

And towards the end of the handshake failure find the 'Invalidated' logger:

> update handshake state: change_cipher_spec upcoming
>   handshake states: client finished[20] upcoming handshake states:
>   server change_cipher_spec[-1] upcoming handshake states: server
>   finished[20] http-nio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec,
>   length = 1
>   *** Finished verify_data:  { 124, 94, 237, 141, 218, 48, 210, 88, 98, 142, 112, 197 }
>   *** update handshake state: finished[20] upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1] upcoming handshake states: server
>   finished[20] http-nio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length =
>   40 http-nio-8080-exec-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
>   http-nio-8080-exec-3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure %%
>   ***Invalidated:  [Session-6, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]***
>   http-nio-8080-exec-3, called closeSocket() http-nio-8080-exec-3,
>   handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received
>   fatal alert: handshake_failure 2019-12-07 23:00:43.732  INFO   ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-3] .v.w.t.MyServiceHandler : @@@@@@@@@ Other Exception
>   happened in
>   MyServiceHandler.execute():com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException:
>   HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received
>   fatal alert: handshake_failure, and the cause
>   is:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP
>   transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal
>   alert: handshake_failure  at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown
>   Source)

From the loggers, I think the SSL protocol version used is TLS1.2 and that looks good. It looks like the Cipher is not matching - but unsure if I am overlooking something and how to remediate this.

On inspecting the logs further, found this one error:

> Unparseable certificate extensions: 1 [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake): ObjectId: 2.5.29.31
>   Criticality=false Unparseable CRLDistributionPoints extension due to
>   java.io.IOException: invalid URI
>   name:ldap://Enroll.visaca.com:389/cn=Visa Information Delivery
>   External CA,c=US,ou=Visa International Service
>   Association,o=VISA?certificateRevocationList

Update - 09-Dec -- In consultation with our middleware support team who indicate that the above CRL exception could be a false alarm.

So with that assumption, looking closely at the log and comparing with the steps outlined in [TLS handshake steps wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake).

```
 upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
 upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
 upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
 http-nio-8080-exec-15, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
 *** Finished verify_data:  { 27, 249, 167, 252, 151, 220, 110, 252, 113, 134, 248, 228 }
 *** update handshake state: finished[20]
 upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
 upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
 http-nio-8080-exec-15, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
 http-nio-8080-exec-15, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
 http-nio-8080-exec-15, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
 %% Invalidated:  [Session-6, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
 http-nio-8080-exec-15, called closeSocket() http-nio-8080-exec-15,
 handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received
 fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

The step 'server change_cipher_spec' is where I am suspecting something has gone wrong - though unsure how to debug this further. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: It is the `SSLSession` that has been invalidated here, not the cipher suite. You are attempting to rejoin an expired session. You may need to look at the peer logs for more information.

Comment: Thank you for that pointer. I am now trying to look closer at the logs between Client Hello & ServerHello. https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors

Comment: Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake , I am able to track till step 'ClientKeyExchange'. 'CertificateVerify' message is missing.

Comment: Found one exception during handshake 'Unparseable CRLDistributionPoints extension'. Unsure if this could be the cause. I have now updated the question with this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the issue is resolved.

As expected, 'Unparseable certificate extensions' turned out to be a false alarm.

Finally setting both trust store and key store helped resolve. The key store was also require for client authentication during the SSL Handshake.

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\cert\visatomcat.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass123 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Users\cert\visatomcat.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass123